# I/O Can't Write To File

Tags: python

> Write a function named uniqueWords that counts how many different
>   words there are in each line of an input file and writes that count to
>   a corresponding line of an output file. The input file already exists
>   when uniqueWords is called. uniqueWords creates the output file.
>
> **Input.** The function uniqueWords takes two parameters:
>
> - inFile, a string that is the name of a text file that is to be read. The file that inFile refers to contains only lower case letters
>     and white space (no punctuation marks or other special characters).
> - outFile, a string that is the name of the file to which uniqueWords writes its output.
>
> The input file is in the current working directory. uniqueWords should
>   create the output file in that directory.
>
> **Output.** For each line of inFile, uniqueWords should write a corresponding line to outFile containing a single integer: the number
>   of unique words on the line.
>
> If the content of the file turn.txt is below,
>
> a time to build up a time to break down a time to dance a time to
>   mourn a time to cast away stones a time to gather stones together
>
> the function call
>
> ```
> uniqueWords('turn.txt', 'turnOut.txt')
> ```
>
> should create a file named turnOut.txt with this content:
>
> ```
> 7
> 5
> 8
> ```

This is what I got so far:

```
def uniqueWords(file_input, file_output):
    for line in file_input:
        words = line.split(" ")
        uniqueWords = set(words)
        total = len(uniqueWords)
        file_output.write(str(total) + "\n")

file_input = open("turn.txt", "r")
file_output = open("turnOut.txt", "w")
uniqueWords('turn.txt', 'turnOut.txt')
```

The code is giving me the following error:

> file_output.write(str(total) + "\n") AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Include the traceback in your question.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. If nothing else, your indentation is wrong as posted.

Comment: file_output.write(str(total) + "\n")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: there are unindented blocks, and you should always close a file when you are done with it.

Comment: You open files and then you don't do anything with them.

Comment: My indentation is right I just forgot to indent it when I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that error is that you passed a string into the function.

You pass the name of a file into `uniqueWords`, rather than the file itself. `open` creates a file object, which you can write to because it has a `write` method. You should pass that object instead. The correct code would be.

```
def uniqueWords(file_input, file_output):
    for line in file_input:
        words = line.split(" ")
        uniqueWords = set(words)
        total = len(uniqueWords)
        file_output.write(str(total) + "\n")

file_input = open("turn.txt", "r")
file_output = open("turnOut.txt", "w")
uniqueWords(file_input, file_output)
file_input.close()
file_output.close()
```

Additionally always remember to close open files when you're done with them.

Comment: @JeffHardy No problem! Remember to accept and upvote good answers!